# Increasing partitions and storage requirements

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka server with retention of 2 days and used log storage is around 30GB. I need to add some extra logstash servers in a new group_id. So I was planning on expanding the current partition of 1 to 2.

I know extra storage will be based on lost of different factors but my question is if the data stream to Kafka remains as they are, at a minimum will I tracking at 60GB as apposed to the current 30GB? As I'm under the impression each partition will have a copy each of data arriving?

As a follow up I don't really want to touch my existing logstash setup. The current setup does not specify a group_id. Am I ok to leave this as it is and only specify a group_id for the new logstash server?

Thanks

Comment: Partitions don't copy data. If the Kafka records have keys, and the keys aren't changing, then data will still all exist on one partition